# Remove last three lines from file using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to remove last three lines of file using ansible. I tried using lineinfile but it removed all the lines from file. I have posted below my file and ansible-playbook. I want to remove nfs_config, nfs_share and mount_path using lines using ansible.Thanks in advance.

file.txt

[images]

[tickets]

[unix sockets]

[nfs_config]

nfs_share=

mount_path=

**`Ansible-playbook`**

```
- name: Remove mount path from daemon.conf for clean-daemon

  linefile:

    path: /etc/ovirt-imageio-daemon/daemon.conf

    regexp: "[nfs_config]"

    state: absent
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ini_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html#ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files). The task below will remove the `nfs_config` section from the configuration file

```yaml
    - ini_file:
        path: /etc/ovirt-imageio-daemon/daemon.conf
        section: nfs_config
        state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

`regexp: "[nfs_config]"` is not doing what you want, you need to use "[nfs_config]", otherwise you are matching any character that is between the `[]`. This is why it's removing multiple lines.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Also, just make 3 `lineinfile` command to match `nfs_config`, `nfs_share` and `mount_path`

You could use onee `lineinifile` with a complex regex to match them all, but it will be easier to read/maintain with 3 that are clear.